# Drag and drop not working on ajax loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on drag and drop of images. The first time the page is loaded, dragging the images and dropping them in another div is working fine.
I can resize the dropped images and drag them in the same div.
In a sibebar I have category lists. When I click on a category, then all images related to that category come in the draggable div.
But when I try to drag and resize, then it is not working for the images which were loaded using ajax.

Do I need to use my jquery again for images which are loading using ajax?

Html Code

```
<section class="outfit-maker sized hide-mobile">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

    <div class="col canv droppable" id="droppable">

      <!-- this is where the content can be dropped -->

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col" id="col1" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:722px;">
    <div class="loading" style="display: none;"><span class="icon-spinner-gif"></span></div>
    <div id="drag-list" class="drag-list">
      <div>
        <ul class="get-image">

          <!-- each image added here will have the "drag" class -->
          <?php 
                          $args = array( 'post_type'=>'products', 'posts_per_page' =>-1,'order' => 'ASC');
                          $query=new WP_Query($args);
                          while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                          $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );  

                        ?>

            <li><span data-item-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" id="drag-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="drag resize-img img-id<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-label="<?php echo the_field('shop_title') ?>" data-shop="<?php echo the_field('shop') ?>" data-unit="<?php echo the_field('unit_no') ?>">
                                     <img data-src-full="<?php echo $url; ?>"  src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="drag-image component" data-img-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">

                                </span>
            </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

This is my code of drag and drop

```
    function elementDrag(el){
  el.draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        }    
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 //elementDrag(data)    
 //makemedragable();


  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',   
    url: MyUrl.ajaxurl, //Including ajax file
    data: {"action": "get_cat_products","status":"0"}, 
    success: function(data){ //Show returned data using the function.

        elementDrag(data);
        jQuery(".get-image").html(data);
         makemedragable();

    }
    });  


}); 

function makemedragable() {

  var x = null;

  jQuery(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    activeClass: "drop-area",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      if (jQuery(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {

        x = ui.helper.clone();
        ui.helper.remove();

        jQuery(".droppable .resize-img").css({
          "display": "inline-table",
          "height": "131px",
          "width": "118px"
        });
        /* To show Controls first time on Dragged Image*/
        var droppedItemId = ui.draggable.attr("data-item-id");


        var dataunit = ui.draggable.attr("data-unit");
        var datalabel = ui.draggable.attr("data-label");
        var datashop = ui.draggable.attr("data-shop");

        jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id", droppedItemId);

        jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(4)").text("ITEM: " + datalabel);
        jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(5)").text("SHOP: " + datashop);
        jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(6)").text("UNIT NO: " + dataunit);


        jQuery(".droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide(); // To show Controls
        jQuery(".controls").show();

        dragEl = jQuery(this);
        stopPosition = dragEl.position();
        var height = x.height(); // To show the controls with exact position
        var width = x.width();
        var mytop = stopPosition.top + height;
        var myleft = stopPosition.left + width / 2;

        jQuery(".controls").css({
          "top": mytop,
          "left": myleft,
          "display": "block"
        });

        x.draggable({
          helper: 'original',
          cursor: 'move',
          containment: '.droppable',
          tolerance: 'fit',

          drop: function(event, ui) {
            jQuery(ui.draggable).remove();

          },
          drag: function() {

          },
          stop: function() {

            dragEl = jQuery(this);
            stopPosition = dragEl.position();
            stopOffset = dragEl.offset();
            document_id = dragEl.data("document-id");
            signer_id = dragEl.data("signer-id");
            var height = x.height();
            var width = x.width();
            var mytop = stopPosition.top + height;
            var myleft = stopPosition.left + width / 2;

            jQuery(".controls").css({
              "top": mytop,
              "left": myleft,
              "display": "block"
            });

            dataItem = jQuery(this).attr('data-item-id');
            jQuery(".droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
            jQuery(".controls").hide();
            jQuery(this).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
            var dataunit = jQuery(this).attr("data-unit");
            var datalabel = jQuery(this).attr("data-label");
            var datashop = jQuery(this).attr("data-shop");
            jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(4)").text("ITEM: " + datalabel);
            jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(5)").text("SHOP: " + datashop);
            jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(6)").text("UNIT NO:" + dataunit);
            jQuery(".controls").show();
            jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id", dataItem);

          }

        });

        x.resizable({
          maxHeight: jQuery('.droppable').height(),
          maxWidth: jQuery('.droppable').width(),
          aspectRatio: true,
          helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
          handles: "nw, ne, sw,se"
        });

        x.addClass('remove');

        x.appendTo('.droppable');

        jQuery(".droppable .drag").on('click', function(e) {


          var dataItem = jQuery(this).attr("data-item-id");
          jQuery(".droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
          jQuery(".controls").hide();
          jQuery(this).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
          var dataunit = jQuery(this).attr("data-unit");
          var datalabel = jQuery(this).attr("data-label");
          var datashop = jQuery(this).attr("data-shop");
          jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(4)").text("ITEM: " + datalabel);
          jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(5)").text("SHOP: " + datashop);
          jQuery(".controls li:nth-child(6)").text("UNIT NO: " + dataunit);
          jQuery(".controls").show();
          jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id", dataItem);

        });

      }
    }
  });


  /* To remove the Element on remove click */
  jQuery(".droppable .controls li.canvas-remove-item").on('click', function(e) {
    var removeId = jQuery(".controls").attr("controls-item-id");
    jQuery('.droppable .resize-img').filter('[data-item-id = ' + removeId + ']').remove();
    jQuery(".droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
    jQuery(".controls").hide();

  });

  //var a =2;
  jQuery(".droppable .controls li.front-item").on('click', function(e) {
    var frontId = jQuery(".controls").attr("controls-item-id"); //alert(frontId);
    jQuery('.droppable .resize-img').removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
    jQuery('.droppable .resize-img').filter('[data-item-id = ' + frontId + ']').addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
  });

  jQuery(".droppable .controls li.back-item").on('click', function(e) {
    var backId = jQuery(".controls").attr("controls-item-id");
    jQuery('.droppable .resize-img').removeClass('bottom').addClass('top');
    jQuery('.droppable .resize-img').filter('[data-item-id = ' + backId + ']').addClass('bottom').removeClass('top');
  });

  jQuery(".droppable").click(function(e) {
    // matches all children of droppable, change selector as needed
    if (jQuery(e.target).closest(".drag").length > 0) {
      jQuery(e.target).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
      jQuery(".controls").show();
    } else {
      jQuery(".droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
      jQuery(".controls").hide();
    }
  });

}
```

And this code to load category images.

```
  /* Show Style Borad Category Product on Click */

      jQuery(".my-sub-cat").click(function() {

        var catId = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 
        jQuery('.loading').css('display', 'block');
        jQuery('#drag-list').addClass('js-loading-overlay');
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',   
        url: MyUrl.ajaxurl, //Including ajax file
        data: {"action": "get_cat_products", "catId":catId}, 
        success: function(data){ //Show returned data using the function.
            jQuery('.loading').css('display', 'none');  
            jQuery('#drag-list').removeClass('js-loading-overlay');
            elementDrag(data);
             makemedragable();
            //alert(data);
            jQuery(".get-image").html(data);
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error comes from

```
 jQuery(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true
  });
```

Do this instead :

```
jQuery(".get-image .drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true,
    /* stop: function (event, ui) { ... } */

});
jQuery(".droppable .drag").draggable({ });
```

And in your document ready, only write this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  makemedragable();
});
```

Here's the copy of your entire custom.js file, modified:
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/fxvpgfvL/1/

Comment: I have changed my jquery above. Please have a look. But it is not working.

Comment: Now i am able to drag and drop the images using ajax. But it is creating problem. When first time i came on page and drag the image it is working fine. then i click on category and it load more images and drag drop working fine. But when i try to drag the first image again i have dragged first time then it is not working.drag is working only for last image.

Comment: I have added html also. I can also provide you link where i am checking it if you need.

Comment: After loading the image drag any image and drop in blank div. then click on any category it will load mages. then drag any image from this. after dragging drag the two images. drag of loding images will work fine but the image that you drag first time after page load it will not draggable.

Comment: It is not working. Showing error   "cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'"

Comment: yes you are right first 2 images are not draggable only 3rd is draggable. if i drag 2 images from same category then 2 images are draggable. but when i click on second category and drag image from that then the previous images are not draggable.only current category loaded images are draggable.

Comment: yes on category click   jQuery(".my-sub-cat").click(function()
{}    and first time images are loading directly  in this ul. <ul class="get-image"></ul>. You can see it in html.

Comment: @php_dev actually problem is from  `helper: 'clone' `. See my updated answer. Anyway, please delete useless comments as they are not needed anymore and make this a long post. Thanks

Comment: but if i remove the clone then origional image will be dragged and dropped. I need only copy of dragged image.

Comment: I have changed my code. but it is showing "el.draggable is not a function" error.

Comment: Okay Do i need to add only class name that you have mentioned in mymydivdragable() function?

Comment: @php_dev yes, only do as I suggested, please. Don't mix answers ;) Or try and copy paste the whole code https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/fxvpgfvL/ in your custom.js I've changed what you need

Comment: Yes i have changed this but it stops drag and drop function.

Comment: Yes darg and drop is working now. but all my functions stops now.like when an image is selected then there are controls like bring to front and front to back. Do i need to add class with front of them also?

Comment: I have updated my jQuery('.controls'). with jQuery(this) but no control is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107251/discussion-between-php-dev-and-virginielgb).